# User.objects.create() does nothing. (Django)

Tags: python, django, orm, backend

I have a view that should run User.objects.create() for the user registration.

```
User.objects.create(name="request.POST['name']", username="request.POST['username']", password="request.POST['password']")
```

It obviously passes the conditionals into this code because it runs the redirect I put after it.

But When testing the registration, it just doesn't create a new entry in the database. What's wrong with it?

Comment: The formatting of your params shows something is not right about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove double quotations.Like below,

`User.objects.create(name=request.POST['name'], username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])`

Answer (score 1):

You have your parameters wrapped in quotes which is not doing what you actually want.

Remove the quotes to properly access `request.POST` and put in the appropriate data:

```
User.objects.create(name=request.POST['name'], ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the quotes wrapped around request.POST[........  as others have commented.

Comment: Calling `save()` is only necessary if you create the user with `User(name=...)`. If you use `User.objects.create(...)`, creating and saving happens in a single step.